# Async JS : The console log displays the data as text but the HTML DIV renders [Promise Object]

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamic resultArray numbers.The console.log(data) shows the data text I want from the API. But the div in the HTML returns a [Object Promise] .

```js
let resultArray = ['6']

  const getUrl = (num) => `http://numbersapi.com/${num}`;
  const getFacts = async (num) => {
    try {
      const resp = await fetch(getUrl(num));
      const data = await resp.text();
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

let theQuote = document.getElementById("quote");
theQuote.textContent = getFacts(resultArray);  // [object promise]
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body class="main">
    <div id="quote"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't sure but it may work for you.

```
(async () => {
    let theQuote = document.getElementById("quote");
theQuote.textContent = await getFacts(resultArray);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

cuz your function getFacts() return a promise and you need to resolve it when use it , try to render data inside the function to avoid this

```
let theQuote = document.getElementById("quote");
let resultArray = ['6']

  const getUrl = (num) => `http://numbersapi.com/${num}`;
  const getFacts = async (num) => {
    try {
      const resp = await fetch(getUrl(num));
      const data = await resp.text();
      console.log(data);
theQuote.textContent = data;  
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you just need to wait until the promise from getFacts gets resolved. You can achieve that by using `then` method of the promise like below:

```js
getFacts(resultArray).then((facts) => {
  let theQuote = document.getElementById("quote");
  theQuote.textContent = facts;
})
```